# adding device to provisioning profile when not using Xcode

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing an app with Phonegap Build.
I have added device in the device section of my iOs dev center account. I have regenerated the provisioning profile and uploaded it to Phonegap Build.
But the app won't install on the new device.

I am not using Xcode. (linux)

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to check the new device when prompted in the process of regenerating the provisioning profile on the iOS dev center.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this would help!
-Try to first download the provisioning profile and make sure it is a development profile and your device is indicated as development device when you generate that profile.
-Go to XCode->Preferences->Accounts->View Details , then click the refresh icon.
-Add your provisioning profile to your device,by going to Window->Organizer->Devices, make sure your device is connected
[image]
-Then add your profile from here
[image]

---

Finaly make sure you chose the right code signing profile before you run your app

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention I am not using Xcode. I am uploading the provisionning profile to Phonegap Build.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to take Xcode, right click on it in the dock, and do application loader. And do that.

If that's not it, go into your project in Xcode and sign in with the profile and archive it. Then you can load it by plugging it in.